# R: instrument function to capture all assignments

Tags: r, function, scope

Given a regular R function `f`, I'd like to be able to create a new function `f_debug` that acts just like `f`, but lets me keep track of all the assignments to function-local variables that happened inside it.

For example:

```r
f <- function(x, y) {
  z <- x + y
  df <- data.frame(z=z)
  df
}

# This function doesn't work as intended - would like it to (in the case of `f` above)
# write out a list containing `z` and `df` to an RDS file
capturing <- function(func) {
  e <- new.env()
  altered <- function(...) {
    parent <- parent.frame()
    e <- something...(func, environment(), parent, etc., etc.)
    result <- func(...)
    saveRDS(as.list(e), 'foo.rds')
    result
  }
  environment(func) <- e
  altered
}

f_debug <- capturing(f)
```

I'm not sure whether my knowledge gap to do this is large or small, anyone have a solution?

Comment: do you need the variables `z` and `df` or the values that the variables stores in case the function is run?

Comment: @Onyambu I would like to retrieve the values that `z` and `df` have at the end of any particular run of the function.  This is similar to the `within` built-in R function, which runs your code and then examines what names have been assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is already implemented in base R with `utils::dump.frames`, in an even more sophisticated way. It saves the frame (environment) associated with each call in the call stack to an object of class `"dump.frames"`, which you can explore retroactively with `utils::debugger` as if you had actually run your code under a debugger.

```r
capturing <- function(func, ...) {
    cc <- as.call(c(quote(utils::dump.frames), list(...)))
    cc <- call("on.exit", cc, add = TRUE)
    body(func) <- call("{", cc, body(func))
    func
}
```

`capturing` injects the call `on.exit(utils::dump.frames(...), add = TRUE)` into the body of `func` and returns the modified function.
Here, `...` is a list of arguments to `dump.frames`:

- `dumpto`, a character string giving the name to be used for the `"dump.frames"` object
- `to.file`, a logical flag indicating whether the `"dump.frames"` object should be assigned in the global environment or `save`-ed to `paste0(dumpto, ".rda")` in the current working directory
- `include.GlobalEnv`, a logical flag indicating whether the global environment should be saved as well

A quick example, which you should try yourself:

```r
tmp <- tempfile()
dir.create(tmp)
cwd <- setwd(tmp)

f <- function(x, y) {
    z <- x + y
    z + 1
}
g <- capturing(f, dumpto = "zzz", to.file = TRUE)
h <- function(a, b) {
    d <- g(a, b)
    d + 1
}
h12 <- h(1, 2)

load("zzz.rda")
zzz
## $`h(1, 2)`
## <environment: 0x14c16cb58>
## 
## $`#2: g(a, b)`
## <environment: 0x14c16ca40>
## 
## attr(,"error.message")
## [1] ""
## attr(,"class")
## [1] "dump.frames"

ls(zzz[[1L]])
## [1] "a" "b"

ls(zzz[[2L]])
## [1] "z" "x" "y"

utils::debugger(zzz)
## Message:  Available environments had calls:
## 1: h(1, 2)
## 2: #2: g(a, b)
## 
## Enter an environment number, or 0 to exit  
## Selection: 2
## Browsing in the environment with call:
##    #2: g(a, b)
## Called from: debugger.look(ind)
## Browse[1]> ls()
## [1] "x" "y" "z"
## Browse[1]> x == 1 && y == 2 && z == x + y
## [1] TRUE
## Browse[1]> Q

setwd(cwd)
unlink(tmp, recursive = TRUE)
```

See `?browser` if you are unfamiliar with R's environment browser.

My `capturing` function has the limitation that `on.exit` calls in the body of `func` must also use `add = TRUE`. If you have written `func` yourself, then it is not much of a limitation at all, and passing `add = TRUE` is a good habit anyway.

Ultimately, there is no completely safe way to inject code into functions, but, in an interactive setting, I would say that this level of "unsafety" is fine.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1: Steal the function's code

Here's a solution which doesn't return a new function which captures intermediate calculations, but rather calls the given function's code internally. There's some limitations, such as it probably only works with named arguments. Instead of storing the intermediate calculations as an RDS, it attaches them as an attribute.

```
capturing <- function(fun, ...) { 
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  code <- body(fun)
  parent <- environment(fun)
  env <- new.env(parent = parent)
  for (val in names(list(...))) {
    env[[val]] <- list(...)[[val]]
  }
  result <- eval(code, envir = env, enclos = parent.frame())
  attr(result, "intermediate") <- env
  result
}

my_add <- function(x, y) {
  z <- x+y
  u <- x-y
  w <- x*y
  x + y
}

intermediates <- function(x) {
  attr(x, "intermediate", exact = TRUE)
}

value <- capturing(my_add, x = 1, y = 7)
ls(envir = intermediates(value))
#> [1] "u" "w" "x" "y" "z"
intermediates(value)$x
#> [1] 1
# Created on 2022-02-08 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

### Solution 2: Modify the function's code

One weakness of this solution is that if the chosen function features a call to `on.exit(add=FALSE)`, some additional work needs to be done to modify the function so the internal environment is captured. However, it does work when the function accepts `...` arguments.

```r
my_add <- function(x, y) {
  z <- x+y
  u <- x-y
  w <- x*y
  x + y
}

insert_capture <- function(code) {
  # `<<-` assigns into the global environment if no variable of the given name is found
  # while traveling up to the global environment. If you need this assignment to go elsewhere,
  # I'd recommend passing in `assign()`. Of course, you could also modify the `on.exit()`
  # to use saveRDS.
  parse(text=append(deparse(code), 
                            "on.exit(._last_capture <<- environment(), add = TRUE)",
                            after = 1L))
}
capturing2 <- function(fun) {
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  code <- insert_capture(body(fun))
  body(fun) <- code
  fun 
}

my_add2 <- capturing2(my_add)

my_add2(1, 7)
#> [1] 8
ls(envir = ._last_capture)
#> [1] "u" "w" "x" "y" "z"
._last_capture$u
#> [1] -6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, `<<-` seems natural here, though I wonder if `body(func) <- call("{", quote(e <<- environment()), body(func))` would be simpler and safer than your injection of `on.exit`. (Not to suggest that anything like this is completely "safe".)